# 2 Subnets + NAS Storage

Tags: router, nas, storage

I have two networks and I want my main PC to be able to connect to the secondary router(Router B) which has the NAS storage on upstairs.

```
Router A - 192.168.0.1 (Main Router with WAN)
Router B - 192.168.1.1
```

If I am on the WiFi on Router B I can connect to Router A perfectly fine but it doesn't work both ways.

I have been trying a few things but I can't seem to get it to work properly and just wanted a push in the right direction.

Router B connect to Router A via Powerline Adapters, If I go into Router A's Web Panel I can see that the IP Address is 192.168.0.14. I thought if I connected to http://192.168.0.14 it would take me to the Web Panel for the other router and also the network storage.

No luck either way.